# Can one convert if they are already in the process when mashiach comes?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, messiah

If there is no more conversion once moshiach comes, what would be the status of a goy in the process?

so if someone was already in the process of converting to orthodox judaism but had yet to stand before the beit dein, have brit milah, and immerse in a mikveh, would the person still be allowed to finish their conversion if moshiach came?